# Unable to install Modelio Open SOurce 4.1 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, dependencies

Steps I follow:
I have downloaded the software from Modelio's website.
Open the terminal.
cd to Downloads
ls to list Download's content
sudo dpkg -i and the software's name

I get this:
dpkg: error processing package modelio-open-source4.1 (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

I also have tried in the GUI area by using Ubuntu's Software and I get:

Unable to install modelio-open-source4.1:
The following packages have unmet dependencies

How to solve that ?

THANKS IN ADVANCE !!

Answer (score 2):

You have to download the dependencies from 18.04 LTS repository and install them with ModelIO package on 20.04 LTS using APT by using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads # use correct folder here where ModelIO deb is stored
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/webkitgtk/libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/webkitgtk/libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb ./libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb ./libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./modelio-open-source_4.1.0_ubuntu_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 30/01/2022 for Ubuntu 20.04 the library

```
libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
```

isn't available anymore and it's replaced by

```
libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
```

should be used.
So the reponse should now be

```
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/webkitgtk/libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/webkitgtk/libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
    
sudo apt-get install ./libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb ./libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb ./libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
```

It works on my machine.