# Install modelio on 21.10

Tags: software-installation

Is there any way to install Modelio on Ubuntu 21.10?  I tried doing it this way: [Unable to install Modelio Open SOurce 4.1 on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368322/unable-to-install-modelio-open-source-4-1-on-ubuntu-20-04) but it doesn't work anymore.

edit:
When trying to follow the process stated in the link I get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 : Depends: libenchant1c2a (>= 1.6.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When trying to install Modelio I get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 modelio-open-source4.1 : Depends: libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Do you receive an error while installing or opening the application? If so, what does the error say? 

Comment: It's telling you that you. need to `sudo apt install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0` (and its dependencies).

Comment: I know that, but that package is obsolete.  The link I posted had a way of doing it a few months ago, but it doesn't work on 21.10.  Thus the question.

Comment: Set up a development environment (`sudo apt install build-essential`), download and build Modelio. You may have to change Modelio to use current libraries.  Always install the `-dev` version of libraries you're developing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help.  Was able to compile myself using nix and running it using jdk8 (will not run on higher versions).  The following links were really helpful to do it, in case anybody needs to do it in the future:

Installing nix: https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix_Installation_Guide

Compiling it: https://www.modelio.org/forum/8-installation/4867-failed-to-compile-on-org-modelio-app-editors-richnote-libreoffice.html

Switching to jdk8: [Downgrading Java 11 to java 8?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133216/downgrading-java-11-to-java-8)

The compiled product gets stored it ./products/target/products/org.modelio.product/linux/gtk/x86_64/Modelio 4.1